# How to make custom scroll by css?

Tags: css, scrollbar, custom-scrolling

I'm facing a problem. I'm working with a website. At there, I've to put a customize scroll bar. I haven't any idea how can I put that. Can you please help me how can I use customize scroll bar instead of default scroll bar by css(this is the scroll bar what I need: https://i.stack.imgur.com/USGlx.jpg)? For now, I've used just the default scroll bar: http://abidhasan.zxq.net/Fysiovisiq

```
.twitter_middle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 166px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Also can you please give me idea how can I make that customize scroll bar cross browser compatible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and jqueryUI go to see their sites you'll find it all there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery custom content scroller. It's cross-browser compatible and is well written & easy to use. [Here is a guide.](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Comment: Thanks. Though I couldn't do exactly what I need, but it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Tiny Scrollbar can be used for scrolling content. It was built using the javascript jQuery library. Also is very easy to use and style with css

example :http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

Comment: Thanks. Though I couldn't do exactly what I need, but it helped me a lot.